# how to get executable of dumpcap?

Tags: reinstall, wireshark

I was trying to remove wireshark from my system. Unfortunately at that time, I removed bumpcap file from /usr/bin folder using rm command. Now I am reinstalling an application wireshark. It's asking for dumpcap executable file.

Answer (score 2):

The executable `dumpcap` is part of the `wireshark-common` package. Run the following to *reinstall* this package:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall --no-install-recommends install wireshark-common
```

And this should be enough to restore this package and enable you to then get `wireshark` up and running...

References:

- [Ubuntu Packages: dumpcap search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=dumpcap&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any)

Comment: `--no-install-recommends` might be an extra option to include.